# JMeter Graph Results for multiple http requests

Tags: http, graph, listener, jmeter

I created a simple JMeter Http test.

I specified 50 users, each users will do do 30 http requests (one after the other), and the user's ramp up time is 1 second.

Then I added a Graph Result Listener, then recorded the performance of my application for 10minutes.

Question : What is Graph Results Listener measuring - per http request of each user? or all 30 http requests of each user?

I mean, if I have an Average of 5seconds, does that mean that the each http requests gets a response 5 seconds on average? ...or does that mean that all 30 http requests (totaling their response times) gets 5 seconds on average?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean, if I have an Average of
>   5seconds, does that mean that the each
>   http requests gets a response 5
>   seconds on average? ...or does that
>   mean that all 30 http requests
>   (totaling their response times) gets 5
>   seconds on average?

This depend how you created your test plan. But if you have one action (which is the HTTP request) and you specified 30 iterations with 50 users, then it means that 5 sec is the average time for the action performed 50 * 30 times.